# JNI call from C++ , FindClass & import

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface, orientdb

I'm accessing a Java class from C++ using JNI, but `FindClass` always returns `nil` whenever I call a certain method in my java file (see java code). When i remove the call, it works ok.

./testjnisamplecode

RESULT: With `graph = new OrientGraphNoTx(odb);` in java code ...

```
No !
```

RESULT: Without `graph = new OrientGraphNoTx(odb);` in java code ...

```
Yes !

Initializing graph ..
```

Java using the command line, it works fine:

```
java -cp "/mypath/orientdb/debug/orientdb-c/lib/*:." Inserter
```

RESULT:

```
Initializing graph .. 
Initialized ok ..
```

**C++**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>

void main()
{

  JavaVM *vm;
  JNIEnv *env;
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

  JavaVMOption opts[2];
  opts[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/mypath/orientdb/debug/orientdb-c:/mypath/orientdb/debug/orientdb-c/lib:/mypath/orientdb/debug/orientdb-c/lib/blueprints-core-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/mypath/orientdb/debug/orientdb-c/lib/blueprints-orient-graph-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:.";
  opts[1].optionString = "-verbose:jni";   

  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
  vm_args.nOptions = 0;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 1;

  jmethodID mid;
  jint square;

  // Construct a VM
  jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);

  // First get the class that contains the method you need to call
  jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Inserter");

  // TEST IF CLASS WAS FOUND
  if (clazz) {
    printf("Yes !\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("No !\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  // get init method
  jmethodID init = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "<init>",
                                 "()V");

}
```

**Java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphNoTx;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.graph.OGraphDatabase;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.TransactionalGraph;
//import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;

import java.util.List;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OType;

public class Inserter
{
    private OGraphDatabase odb;
    private OrientGraphNoTx graph;

    public Inserter() 
    {
        System.out.println("Initializing graph .. ");

        odb = new OGraphDatabase("local:/home/vagrant/orientdb-graphed-1.5.1/databases/sitepoint-ruby-demo").open("admin","admin");

        //graph = new OrientGraphNoTx(odb);    // <----- THIS BREAKS C++ CODE

        //System.out.println("Initialized ok .. ");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Inserter ins = new Inserter();
    }
}
```

How can i fix this??? Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like a class loader issue(i.e. not finding the OrientGraphNoTx class ). With verbose turned on, you should see something being sent to stderr on the failed FindClass call.  You could also check for exceptions(`ExceptionCheck` & `ExceptionDescribe` )

Answer (score 0):

I think are missed the orientdb jars in the classpath, are not enough the blueprints api, you need to include also orient-commons.jar and orientdb-core.jar ( blueprints-orient-graph dependencies)

bye